# permission in Map view on osmdroid at Api 25

Tags: android, permissions, openstreetmap, osmdroid

according **osmdroid** wiki I added `"dangerous" permissions at runtime`:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (hasPermissions()) {
        initMap();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (hasPermissions()) {
            initMap();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

but for first time when I run my app and give permission location and other needed permission my map does not appear but for second time when I run my app , map is appear? I know this problem is for permission but where is the my permission problem ?

```
    private boolean hasPermissions() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

this is my manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I put :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

into the initMap(), the problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a few seconds delay before calling ***initMap()*** in ***onRequestPermissionsResult()***

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (hasPermissions()) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initMap();
            }
        }, 3000);

    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

The updated permissions sometimes take time in reflecting into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, I found the following code snippet from **osmdroid** official wiki, and It's work for me.
(I'm using version 6.0.1)

Try to put the following code when Activity or Fragment onCreate():

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

After grant "dangerous" permissions in runtime, **Recreate** the Activity or Fragment. Then the mapView will works normally without reopen the APP.